# In cuda do threads of a block act on consecutive array elements or do they act arbitrarily?

Tags: cuda

If there are 5 blocks with 10 threads each and we have to perform some operation on array that has length of 50, will my first block will act on first 10 array elements and then threads from second block will act on next 10 elements and so on. Is this the case?

I asked this because

I had 2 images, i found difference pixel by pixel, where the difference is above certain threshold made that pixel 1 else 0. then shown this binary image. now there are some very little differences also coming which i want to ignore. i did summation of pixel values block by block and if some block has number of 1s smaller than some threshold, i made it to 0. but now there are few extra places also disappearing because there ones are at corners of blocks.
what can I do?

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos I asked this question because I want to overlap my blocks. e.g. a block with id 0 worked on say first 10 elements then i want my next block with id 1 work on next 5 elements and previous 5 elements from block 0. is this possible?

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos I thought it is related to scheduling as block with id 0 may have worked on first 10 array elements but block with id 1 worked on different array elements not necessarily next 10 array elements. but it is not the case?
what i understand is blocks execute at different order but consecutive blocks work on consecutive array elements.

Comment: @AndreasPapadopoulos ok i have edited. please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused on how CUDA works. CUDA is not an auto-vectorizer. Let me explain:

Say, you have an image `A` and `B` and want to perform a pixel-by-pixel difference between those two, producing an image `C`. In a highly-specialized DSL you might write `C = A-B`, and let the language automatically figure out all the indexing needed. In such a language it would make sense to ask, how exactly the indexing is done.

But this is not what happens in CUDA. Here, *you* provide the indexing. As you probably know, when launching a kernel, you spawn several blocks, each containing several threads. Each thread is identified by a built-in value `threadIdx` and `blockIdx`. You *have to* use these to index your images. For example:

```
int globalIndex = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
C[globalIndex] = A[globalIndex] - B[globalIndex];
```

In such a setup consecutive threads access the neighbouring pixels of your images. You could index it differently, for example:

```
int globalIndex = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
if (globalIndex % 32 == 0)
    C[globalIndex/32] = A[globalIndex/32] - B[globalIndex/32];
```

Now every 32-th thread access the neighbouring pixels. The other threads do nothing. It would be about 32 times slower, but it is your choice to do so. You control this.

Of course these are the simplest examples. You may want to work on 2D image instead. You may want to check the boundaries of these images. You may want to launch 2D kernel. Those are all your choices that CUDA language does not make for you.

For that reason there is no definite answer to your question. It is *you* who assign threads to cells in an array. It will be what you choose it to be.

What you *cannot* control is the order of execution. It may be that thread 256 executes before thread 0. But that is another topic, which you didn't ask in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The memory access pattern is freely programmable, so this depends entirely on your code.

Each thread is given individual [threadIdx and blockIdx](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy) variables, which it can then use to calculate array indices or addresses as it desires.

However it is generally a good idea to make consecutive threads access consecutive locations in memory, [as this is more efficient](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses).

As the hardware groups threads in to [warps](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture) of 32 threads, it is also a good idea to make the blocksize a multiple of at least 32 so that no resources go unused. Blocksizes that are multiples of 64 might be even more efficient as some resources (registers) are allocated for 2 warps at a time.

The [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html), is a good place to start reading, particularly the chapter on the programming model. The [CUDA C Best Practices Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html) has further information on how to tune code for best performance.

Comment: @MattoShahzad: No it is not.

Comment: @talonmies the dude in above comments said it is certainly possible.

Comment: @MattoShahzad: No. that isn't what the answer says at all. You can have whatever thread to memory indexing arrangement you like. However, you cannot control the order in which blocks will run, nor can a block know its execution order while it is running.